# Listing matrix from batch file

Tags: batch-file, matrix

I need to make batch file that takes two arguments.

First is txt file containing matrix A containing integer values delimited by ','.

Second argument is also txt file. It containts array B of integers delimited by ' '.

Batch file should create file named result.txt which contains matrix C, where 
`C[i][j]=A[i][j]+k[i][j]` where `k[i][j]` is number of occurrence number `A[i][j]` in array B. I would be very thankful if anyone could help me. I tried to solve this but for command in dos is killing me...

For example:

**`matrix.txt`**

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

**`array.txt`**

```
1 3 2 5 1
```

**`results.txt`**

```
3 3 4

4 6 6
```

Comment: Questions resembling "Write this for me.  Here are my requirements." aren't well-received around here.  See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips, and either revise or delete your question quickly before the flood of downvotes begins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("path+array.txt") do (
  set "array_all=%%a"
)
set array_n=0
call :sub_2 %array_all%
set array_n_all=%array_n%

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("path+matrix.txt") do (
  set "current_line=%%a"
  set "current_line=!current_line:,= !"
  set "matrix_new="
  call :sub_1 !current_line!
  echo !matrix_new:~1!>>"path+results.txt"
)
exit /b

:sub_1
set "current_value=%1"
if not defined current_value exit /b
set "array_rest=!array_all:%current_value%=!"
set array_n=0
call :sub_2 %array_rest%
set /a current_value_new=%current_value%+%array_n_all%-%array_n%
set "matrix_new=%matrix_new% %current_value_new%"
shift
goto sub_1

:sub_2
set "array_tmp=%1"
if not defined array_tmp exit /b
set /a array_n+=1
shift
goto sub_2
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem is interesting! This is how I would solve it:

```
rem Count the number of times each number appear in array B
for each line in %2 do (
   for each number %%n in line do (
      add 1 to times[%%n]
   )
)

rem Process the matrix A
for each line in %1 do (
   rem Initialize output line
   set "out="
   for each number %%n in line do (
      set termC = %%n + times[%%n]
      join termC to out
   )
   echo out
)
```

**EDIT**: As user aschipfl indicated, this answer is just the pseudo-code of how to solve this problem that I posted as a hint for you (because post complete solutions when the OP had not showed his/her own efforts to solve the problem is not a good practice here).

However, now that another working solution had been posted, I completed previous pseudo-code into a fully working program:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Check the arguments
if "%~2" equ "" echo Usage: %~NX0 MatrixA.txt ArrayB.txt & goto :EOF
if not exist "%~1" echo MatrixA file not found & goto :EOF
if not exist "%~2" echo ArrayB file not found & goto :EOF

rem Count the number of times each number appear in array B
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%b in ("%~2") do (
   for %%n in (%%b) do (
      set /A "times[%%n]+=1"
   )
)

rem Process the matrix A and create matrix C
(for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%~1") do (
   set "out="
   for %%n in (%%a) do (
      set /A termC=%%n + times[%%n]
      set "out=!out! !termC!"
   )
   echo !out:~1!
)) > result.txt
```

Comment: @aschipfl: I did it, and also added a complete working program